# Exit the Linux shell back to command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With the Windows Subsystem for Linux enabled, you can switch to the Linux shell by running `bash` in command prompt. Is it possible to go the other way, and switch back to the command prompt?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type `exit` to terminate the shell and return to the calling program.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `logout` in bash to return to command prompt.

[image: bash]

Comment: `exit` didn't work for me.  When I tried I got a message `logout There are stopped jobs.` and it remained at the bash prompt.   `logout` worked perfectly to get back to the Windows command prompt.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already answered to use `exit` to back to Command prompt

i was using tmux and i can't use `exit` as it will close the session. instead of going back.

so, i have to use `cmd.exe` to use command prompt o

The best thing is now you can use tmux for command prompt.

Comment: Note this starts a new command prompt rather than exiting the WSL prompt. If you exit this new command prompt you will end up back in WSL.

Answer (score -1):

Build 14951 adds the ability to execute .exe files in Bash. Many Windows executables are in directory /mnt/c/Windows/System32. Bash command names distinguish upper case and lower case letters and include ".exe" suffix.

Comment: This will launch a new cmd prompt, not open in the terminal

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, no.

When running `bash` from the command prompt, it executes the `bash` program.  You can see the executable itself, by typing the following into the command prompt:

> `where bash`

This results is `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`

`Bash` is a *Windows* console application.  That is why you can run it from the command prompt.

It doesnt work the other way around.  Although Bash has file system access to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` (the Windows command prompt), it is not a binary application that it understands.

I suppose you could create a workaround.  You could enable telnet/SSH on Windows and login that way to get the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood what you were asking

Comment: you understood correctly, your answer was just wrong.